# I have a use case which causes issues with Jenkins free style project poll scm

Tags: jenkins

I have a free style project which will trigger on commits. I have kept poll scm which polls for commits in remote repository. This jenkins job actually make some changes to a file after checkout and then commits+push back to remote repository.

This push by jenkins job is actually triggering back a new build due to scm poll for new commits is set in job. I want this job not to trigger again for self commit by job itself

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear if you are using Git. In case you are and expect that the file will be always be changed by Jenkins, Git plugin in freestyle has options to ignore certain file paths.

If this specific file is expected to edited by user other than Jenkins than only solution I can think of is through conditional logic in jenkins pipeline-as-code.